# How to handle a vector of template class?

Tags: c++, templates, vector, stl

i'm working on a quicksort function that sorts a vector of objects created from a template. Specifically a vector of Points on a **n** dimention space. This is my Point template:

```
#ifndef POINT_H   
#define POINT_H   
template <int dimention, typename type>   
class Point{
public:
    Point(){mCoords = new type[dimention];}
    Point(type* pCoords);
    int getDimention(){return dimention;}
// Operators
//-----------
```

This is the quicksort function (i haven't written the actual implementation because i wish to solve this problem first):

```
#ifndef QUICK_S
#define QUICK_S
#include <vector>
#include "point.h"

// Generic quicksort function that works with points of any dimention
std::vector<Point<int dimention, typename type> > 
quicksort(std::vector<Point<int dimention, typename type> > unsorted)
{
// implementation --------------
```

The errors i'm getting (some of them):

```
In file included from convexHull.cpp:4:0:
quicksort.h:7:47: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)

In file included from quicksort.h:4:0,
             from convexHull.cpp:4:
point.h:5:7: error: provided for ‘template<int dimention, class type> class Point’
 class Point{

In file included from convexHull.cpp:4:0:
quicksort.h:7:49: error: template argument 1 is invalid
std::vector<Point<int dimention, typename type> >
```

I would appreciate if you can point where i'm wrong, any tips or ideas are welcome, i'm sort of a self-taught programmer. Thanks.

Comment: You understand that C++ already has `std::sort`, right?

Comment: @MooingDuck The points need to be sorted lexicografically starting from coordinate X, Y, Z and so on to the nth dimension. Can `std::sort` do that?

Comment: @GilLázaro you can pass a custom comparator to `sort`.

Comment: @user657267 Point class already has an overriden < operator. I guess `std::sort`will do fine then.

Comment: @GilLázaro: Yes, if you have `operator<`, then you should be able to "just sort it".  Alternatively: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/041681fcc2aa0f16

Comment: @MooingDuck Nice solution, your code is very clear, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `quicksort` can operate on `vector<Point<int dimention, typename type> >` for any values of `dimention` and `type`, it is a template function and must be declared as such:

```
template<int dimention, typename type>
std::vector<Point<dimention, type> > 
quicksort(std::vector<Point<dimention, type> > unsorted)
```

Also note that the `int` and `typename` in `Point<dimention, type>` are removed here.

Comment: It's also probably worth mentioning that it's unlikely that the proposed sort will perform any better than `std::sort`.  I'd be inclined not to write it at all.

Comment: @Edward there's a good chance it will be worse than `std::sort`, the c library `quicksort` invariably is.

Comment: And, by passing the vector by value, you are not going to sort much more than a copy anyway ...

Answer (score 0):

Your quicksort definition should just declare its template like this:

```
std::vector<typename type> 
quicksort(std::vector<type> unsorted)
{
// implementation --------------
```

whenever you call quicksort, you add the template for your particular Point setup:

```
quicksort<Point<1,float> >(pointList);
```

As per Mooing Duck's comment, in this case, you don't need to supply your template type as it can be deduced by the compiler:

```
quicksort(pointList);
```

should be all you need.

Comment: You don't need to explicitly specify the template parameters in that situation, they can be deduced.

Comment: I suppose that is true too, in this case.